# uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, independence, borel-sets

> Let $\Omega =(0,1)$, $\mathcal{B}=$Borel Set and $P=$ Lebesgue measure. Suppose $X_n(\omega) =\sin (2\pi n\omega),n=1,2, \dots$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

The solution to uncorrelated part is really easy, but stuck on the independent part. I started with the set $A(a)=\{ \omega : X_n(\omega)\in [0,a),X_m(\omega)\in [0,a), m\neq n \}$, As $a$ becomes arbitrarily small the set $A(a)$ contains all points such that $X_n(\omega)$ and $X_m(\omega)$ intersect when they are $0$.

Again let $B(a)=\{ \omega : X_n(\omega)\in [0,a)\}$ and $C(a)=\{ \omega : X_m(\omega)\in [0,a)\}$. So we if independent then $P(A(a))=P(B(a)) P(C(a))$.

It is easy to check that if $a\to 0$, $\# A(a) < \min\{ \# B(a), \# C(a) \}$, here $\# D=$number of elements in $D$. How to claim after that, that $P(A(a))<P(B(a)) P(C(a))??$

(May be everything I wrote is wrong, in that case please help with right solution please!)

Comment: "Suppose" > "Prove". Re your proof, note that every event considered is infinite hence invoking the number of elements is a dead end.

Comment: @Did note for example, $A= \cap_n [0,\frac{1}{n})=\{ 0\}$, then $\# A=1$.  Here as $a\to 0$ we can choose $A=\cap_{n\geq N} A(\frac{1}{n})$ which will give us $\# A$ is finite value, should I edit in this way?

Comment: No, rather you should abandon all hope that sizes of sets are relevant in this context (for the reason I already explained, but).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X_1$ and $X_2$:
$$
P(X_1,X_2\in[0,1])=P([0,1/4])=\frac{1}{4}
$$
but
$$
P(X_1\in[0,1])=\frac{1}{2},\\
P(X_2\in[0,1])=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
Hence, $P(X_1\in[0,1])P(X_2\in[0,1])\neq P(X_1,X_2\in[0,1])$ and thus $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.